# SQL Server SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE not working

Tags: sql-server

I keep getting 'Invalid object name 'SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE' when I try to find documents similar based off their body (I am using SQL Server 2012).

Here's the query:

```
declare @ID int

select  top 1
        @ID = ID
from    dbo.Documents with (nolock)

select  *
from    SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE
        (
            dbo.Documents,
            Body,
            @ID
        )
```

If I run the following, everything returns 1 (indicating that everything is set up correctly as far as the full text search and indexes, I believe):

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('MyDatabase', 'IsFullTextEnabled') [Database_Supported]
GO

SELECT OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Documents'), 'TableFullTextSemanticExtraction') [Table_Supported]
GO

SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Documents'), 'Body', 'StatisticalSemantics') [Column_Search_Supported]
GO

SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_index_columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Documents')
GO
```

Any ideas or tips?

**EDIT**

Just some more info on the table (dbo.Documents):

- ID is the identity column (which also serves as the primary key)
- The Body column represents the body of the document obviously.  It is this column that the full text indexing is enabled, as well as the column the statistical semantics are enabled.
- The semantics database is attached and registered (which I believe some of the above queries confirms.

Comment: What data type is body?

Comment: It is an NVARCHAR (I believe the length is set to MAX).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that the database you are using this with has a compatibility level of at least 2012 (Under database properties then Options).